# How to insert row into Azure: CosmosDB table storage

Tags: azure, binding, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert a record into Azure CosmosDB table storage. I created a Timer function and integrated CosmosDB table storage into output. The below is the function.

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB"

using System;

public static People Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    return new People() { 
            PartitionKey = "0020", 
            RowKey = "1034",  
            Team = "1010"
    };
}

public class People
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the same code by integrating the function with output binding set as **Azure table storage**. It returned *Status: 202 Accepted* with the row inserted. But in **Azure CosmosDB table storage**, I got the same status with no row inserted.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "$return",
      "databaseName": "TablesDB",
      "collectionName": "People",
      "createIfNotExists": false,
      "connection": "sb-leaderboard_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": true
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong, the problem is that Azure Functions do not currently support Azure Cosmos DB Table API.

The problem is that tables use a custom encoding for their documents (entities) and the generic document DB binding doesn't know anything about this encoding. So the binding is happy to write the document you asking it to write but that document isn't in the special encoding that tables uses.

Comment: Thank you. I talked to support people and they asked me to use DocumentDB instead of CosmosDB Table. Are there other ways to Read, write entities to CosmosDB Tables through Azure functions?

Comment: You should be able to read from tables just fine. It's the writing that isn't currently supported but should be fixed real soon now.